# Getting Environment Variable in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

`echo %PATH%` will print the enviroment variable PATH. But I want to assign the environment variable to a batch variable first and then get the value of the environment variable. Is it possible?

Something as follows:

```
set myvar=PATH
echo %myvar%
```

The above code will echo "PATH". But I want to get the enviroment variable PATH

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try with :

> set myvar=PATH
>
> call echo %%myvar%%

or with delayed expansion (it should work faster):

```
@echo off
set myvar=PATH
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !%myvar%!
```

Why you can use directly set `set "myvar=%PATH%"` ?